# Loopback3 calling remote method or API periodically

Tags: node.js, cron, loopbackjs, polling

Basically, my requirement is to keep looking for new files in the folder, read the contents of the file and call the loopback API.

To achieve that I am trying to do something like below:

I have a remote method in loopback which needs to be called periodically i.e. after every 2 minutes. I read about the asynchronous boot scripts in the official loopback documentation here:
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Defining-boot-scripts#synchronous-and-asynchronous-boot-scripts
So far I have been able to write the following code:

```
module.exports = function(app, callback) {
  setInterval(function() {
    console.log('Hello world');
    callback();
  }, 120000);
};
```

But this throws an error below.

```
error: uncaughtException: listen EADDRINUSE :::443
```

Also, is there a way to call remote methods from the bootscripts ? Does loopback support cron/schedular or polling like functionality. Do I need to write a separate nodejs application which will call the API periodically.

Thanks

Comment: Which error it throws?

Comment: sorry, I have updated the question with error message now. Is it the correct way of calling ? Won't it block the other API's ?

Answer (score 0):

Your error states that your address(port number) if the server is already in use.

> error: uncaughtException: listen EADDRINUSE :::443

1. You can try to listen on some other port number

   app.listen(3000, function() {
     console.log('listening on 3000')
   });
2. Kill process running on same port

First, you would want to know which process is using port 3000

```
sudo lsof -i :3000
```

this will list all PID listening on this port, once you have the PID you can terminate it with the following:

```
kill -9 {PID}
```

3. Check if your code is not calling multiple listen on the same port

Let me know if this isn't resolving your problem

Comment: No. I am using http://localhost:443/api to expose the API's I have created using loopback. I am trying to write asynchronous bootscript in the same application. But whenever it hits the callback() it throws this error.